# Integrating Oauth without the user redirect - PHP/Adobe Sign

Tags: php, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

Currently I am looking to integrating an Api using Rest/Oauth - no problem. Adobe Sign.

However, the api integration has nothing to do with the users themselves, it's simple requests on the back-end to call the api. To redirect the users to get an access token/register with the 3rd party isn't suitable.

There is an option in the control panel to generate a "legacy app" access key - **is that the best option**?

Other than that - there doesn't seem to be a way to keep an oauth key permanently active (without using the refresh token), it's not a great idea to refresh it over and over endlessly.

Comment: My boss is pretty adamant about using oauth, even for server to server integrations like this one. No users is involved so I can't do the redirect method of authentication. Has anyone got that to work without using an integration key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably already resolved this, but try using an Integration Key. The "API Information" section of you account should state that "You can create an Integration Key if you have a legacy application which does not support OAuth."; the Integration Key part of that statement providing a link to create one. This is how I use Adobe Sign via REST but without the rigmarole of using OAuth (Client ID / Secrets are fine, but as you've said sometimes the API needs to be used without human intervention).

Comment: Cheers Bob - I did exactly that!